# Does the kube-apiserver expect the presence of kube-proxy?

Tags: kubernetes, flannel, kubelet, kube-proxy

I've been running my kubernetes masters separate from my kubernetes nodes. So I have `kube-apiserver`, `kube-scheduler` and `kube-controllermanager` running on a server without `kubelet`, `kube-proxy` or `flannel`.

So far this has worked perfectly. However, today I attempted to set up the [Web UI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ui/) and access it through an API server. I got the the following error when accessing `http://kube-master-0:8080/ui`:

`Error: 'dial tcp 172.16.72.12:9090: getsockopt: connection timed out'
Trying to reach: 'http://172.16.72.12:9090/'`

This suggests to me that the API server is trying to connect to the pod IP, as we don't have flannel or kube-proxy running on this host, the `172.16.72.12` IP will not be routed.

Am I expected to run kube-proxy and flannel on my API servers? Is there another way to let the API server proxy the UI?

Answer (score 0):

It's not required, but it will certainly make your life easier.

The reason this isn't working is because kube-proxy isn't directing traffic to the service. Try `kube-node:8080/ui` (assuming you have exposed it as with NodePort configuration

Answer (score 0):

In theory, Kube apiserver **does not** expect the presence of kube-proxy.
This means kube apiserver will run correctly, receives requests and handles them(mostly reads from and writes to `etcd`).

But if you want the whole cluster working, you will need other components running, for example:

- if you want `pods` or `deployments` to be scheduled, `kube-scheduler` should be running
- if you want `pods` and `containers` be running in nodes, `kubelet` has to be running
- if you want `replications` can be guarded, `controller-manager` should be runing

As for `kube-proxy` and `flannel`, they are critical parts to make sure networking is working. `Load Balance`, `service`, `across-hosts pod communication` etc all depends on them.